# chidlren в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

подскажите как организовать наполнение модального окна через chidlren. Наполнение данными будет происходить в компонентах First и Second. Модальное окно должно быть одно, подключается через портал. Modal должен быть абстрактным без привязки к компонентам.

```
const App = () => {
const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(null)
const [isModalActive, setIsModalActive] = useState(false)

  const openModal = (content) => {
    setModalData(content)
    setIsModalActive(true)
  }

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalData(null)
    setIsModalActive(false)
  }


  return (
    <>
      <First/>
      <Second/>
      <Modal><Modal/>
    </>
  )
}


const Modal = ({chidlren}) => {

  return CreatePortal((
    <>
      {chidlren}
    </>
  ), document.body)
}
```

Comment: Вот статейка на тему порталов и их заполнения через `chidlren`...

Answer (score 0):

Не пойму чего не спросишь у чат гпт, но вот тебе решение, можешь попробовать
Создайте компонент Modal, который будет представлять модальное окно и использовать порталы для отображения содержимого вне его текущего местоположения в DOM-дереве. В этом компоненте вы можете определить место для динамического содержимого с помощью children.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root'); // DOM-узел, куда 
                     будет отрисовываться модальное окно

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    modalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <div className="modal">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>,
      this.el
    );
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

Создайте компоненты First и Second, которые будут предоставлять содержимое для модального окна.

```
import React from 'react';

const First = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Содержимое из First</h1>
      {/* Добавьте любое нужное содержимое */}
    </div>
  );
}

const Second = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Содержимое из Second</h1>
      {/* Добавьте любое нужное содержимое */}
    </div>
  );
}

export { First, Second };
```

В вашем корневом компоненте (например, App), используйте Modal и решите, какой контент должен быть отображен в модальном окне, например, на основе состояния или событий.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';
import { First, Second } from './YourComponents'; // Замените на свой
```

Comment: Ты так и не показал как будешь наполнять `Modal` чрез `chidlren` из `First` и `Second`

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';

const First = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Содержимое из First</h1>
      {/* Любое содержимое, которое вы хотите отобразить в модальном окне */}
    </div>
  );
}

const Second = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Содержимое из Second</h1>
      {/* Любое содержимое, которое вы хотите отобразить в модальном окне */}
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [showFirstModal, setShowFirstModal] = useState(false);
  const [showSecondModal, setShowSecondModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowFirstModal(true)}>Показать First Modal</button>
      <button onClick={() => setShowSecondModal(true)}>Показать Second Modal</button>

      {showFirstModal && (
        <Modal>
          <First />
          <button onClick={() => setShowFirstModal(false)}>Закрыть</button>
        </Modal>
      )}

      {showSecondModal && (
        <Modal>
          <Second />
          <button onClick={() => setShowSecondModal(false)}>Закрыть</button>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

> как организовать наполнение модального окна через chidlren. Наполнение данными будет происходить в компонентах First и Second. Модальное окно должно быть одно, подключается через портал. Modal должен быть абстрактным без привязки к компонентам

Для твоего исходного кода предложу такой вариант развития...

```js
const First = ({openModal, closeModal}) => {
  const act = _ => openModal((<div>
    <p>Данные первого компонента</p>
    <button onClick={closeModal}>Закрыть</button>
  </div>))
  return <article>
    <h1>First</h1>
    <button onClick={act}>Показать данные первого компонента</button>
  </article>
}

const Second = ({openModal, closeModal}) => {
  const act = _ => openModal((<div>
    <p>Данные втрого компонента</p>
    <button onClick={closeModal}>Закрыть</button>
  </div>))
  return <article>
    <h1>Second</h1>
    <button onClick={act}>Показать данные втрого компонента</button>
  </article>
}

const App = () => {
  const [modalData, setModalData] = React.useState(null)
  const [isModalActive, setIsModalActive] = React.useState(false)

  const openModal = (content) => {
    setModalData(content)
    setIsModalActive(true)
  }

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalData(null)
    setIsModalActive(false)
  }


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <First openModal={openModal} closeModal={closeModal} />
      <Second openModal={openModal} closeModal={closeModal} />
      {isModalActive && <Modal>{modalData}</Modal>}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}


const Modal = ({children}) => {

  return ReactDOM.createPortal((
    <React.Fragment>
      {children}
    </React.Fragment>
  ), document.querySelector('#modal'))
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
#modal > * {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container">
</div><div id="modal"></div>
```